# how to store diffrent stocks data frame in some sort of container and could run some operation in one go on all data frame in that conatiner operation

Tags: pandas, algorithmic-trading

I would like to know how to store different stocks data frame in some sort of container and be able to run some operation in one go on all data frame in that container operation, and would like to calculate daily returns, cum returns etc

I have been using `vars()` function  to do it but that doesn't seem to be a good practice. I want to store data in another way and I don't have any idea how to that.

In my assignment I have been told don't use `vars()` use some thing else

```
for stock in stocks:
    df = pd.read_csv(stock+'_data.csv',index_col=0)
    df.columns
    df['Daily returns'] = df['close'] /df['open'] -1
    vars()['df_'+stock] = df.copy()

    #Calculation of Loss and profit trades
    loss=np.where(vars()['df_'+stock]['Daily returns']<0)# so u see this code is first calling the data frame 'df_'+stock so a stock data is stored in it where we named each stock dataframe
    profit=np.where(vars()['df_'+stock]['Daily returns']>0)

    #Calculation of trade counts
    total_trades = len(vars()['df_' + stock]) # as we are taking a trade evry single day so we can count the lenght of dataframe 
    loss_trades = len(loss[0]) # [0] this argument is there because without this code would return zero 
    profit_trades = len(profit[0])

    #Calculation of hit ratios
    hit_ratio= profit_trades/(loss_trades + profit_trades)
    total_returns=np.cumsum(vars()['df_'+stock]['Daily returns'])    
    vars()['df_'+stock]['Cum Returns']=total_returns 

    stats=[stock,hit_ratio,total_returns[len(total_returns)-1]]
    all_stats.append(stats)
    headings=['Stock Name','Hit Ratio','Final Return']

    #Final Result of all the calculations
    final_result=pd.DataFrame(all_stats, columns=headings)

    plt.plot(vars()['df_'+stock].index.values,vars()['df_'+stock]['Cum Returns'],label=stock)
    plt.legend()
```

results are expected but I don't want to use `vars()` function

Answer (score 1):

Lets talk about what you are currently doing in the hopes that it becomes clear to you what you need to change. So you are currently storing in vars and need to change that. Question 1 is what is `vars()`

> vars([object]) Return the **dict** attribute for a module, class,
>   instance, or any other object with a **dict** attribute.
>
> Objects such as modules and instances have an updateable **dict**
>   attribute; however, other objects may have write restrictions on their
>   **dict** attributes (for example, classes use a types.MappingProxyType to prevent direct dictionary updates).
>
> Without an argument, vars() acts like locals(). Note, the locals
>   dictionary is only useful for reads since updates to the locals
>   dictionary are ignored.

That last part is very important see this section from the doc of `locals()`

> Note The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes
>   may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the
>   interpreter.

So you are currently using a dictionary of the locals that should not be modified because those changes may fail.All you have to do is use a different dictionary.

P.S. Your code is incorrect. It does not compute the correct answer.

**Edit:** For example create a new dictionary `stocks = {}` outside of the loop and replace ever instance of `vars()` with `stocks`

Comment: thanks for clearing the topic but the problem is I don't know how to store data frames in the dictionary it would be great of you if you can show how to store multiple stock data frames in a dictionary

Comment: Updated the answer